# Half hot outlet

Tags: receptacle

Why do both outlets that are supposed to be half hots have power going to all four outlets all the time? The tab is broken. 1 switch 2 outlets.  [image][image]

Comment: Are the tabs on the hot side of BOTH outlets broken?  And could there be a third with an unbroken tab?

Comment: That outlet should really be on pigtails instead of having 2 wires on the screw terminals.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the switch and let the wires hang in air. Do you still have the problem?  I bet you do... somehow the red and black are shorted.

Possibly relating to the way those red and black wires on the receptacle don't look quite right.

"tab" singular -- you broke off the tab on BOTH duplex outlets, right?  Because you need to do that.